# Why $\int_0^1\left|f_n(x)-f_m(x)\right|^2dx <\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}}[(n+1))\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)]^2 \mathrm{~d} x $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

In [these notes](https://carmamaths.org/brailey/Lecture_Notes/NOTES-Intro%20to%20Hilbert%20Spaces.pdf) we read, at page 22, the following argument.

Let $\left(f_n\right)$ be the sequence of functions defined by,

$$
f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
1 & \text { if } 0 \leq x<\frac{1}{2} \\
1-(n+1)\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) & \text { if } \frac{1}{2} \leq x<\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1} \\
0 & \text { if } \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1} \leq x \leq 1
\end{array}\right.
$$

(...) Observe that, without loss of generality taking $m>n$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left\|f_n-f_m\right\|^2 & =\int_0^1\left|f_n(x)-f_m(x)\right|^2 \mathrm{~d} x \\
& <\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}}[(n+1))\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)]^2 \mathrm{~d} x \\
& =\frac{1}{3(n+1)} \\
& \rightarrow 0 \text { as } \mathrm{n} \text { (and hence } \mathrm{m}) \rightarrow \infty
\end{aligned}
$$
Can someone explain to me why $\int_0^1\left|f_n(x)-f_m(x)\right|^2 \mathrm{~d} x 
<\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}}[(n+1))\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)]^2 \mathrm{~d} x $? This inequality is given simply without adding explanations, as if it were a trivial fact, but I cannot understand it.

Comment: When $m<n$, it is certainly true that $f_n \geq f_m$. The only nontrivial interval where the inequality is strict and the differences don't cancel is precisely the largest bounds of integration for when the function is not constant.

Comment: Perhaps it would be clearer if the author instead wrote $< \int_{1/2} ^{1/2 + 1/(n+1)}(1 - (n+1)(x-1/2))^2 dx$, i.e. the integral of $f_n(x)^2$ over $(1/2,1/2+1/(n+1))$. Draw the graph of $f_n$ and $f_m$ and see where they overlap and where they differ. Convince yourself that $m\to \infty$ would give the biggest difference between the two functions.

Comment: @Winther It's not so clear because for $\frac{1}{2} \leq x < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{m+1}$ we have $f_n(x) - f_m(x) = (m-n)\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Comment: @Klaus The key is to realize (which you can see if you draw it) that $|f_n - f_m| < |f_n - f_\infty|$ (on $x\geq 1/2$). And then the interval you mention goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment, it is clear that $f_n(x) \geq f_m(x)$ when $m>n$. The integral is only nonzero on the intervals where $f$ is nonconstant, giving us

$$\int_0^1|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^2dx = \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}} |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^2dx \leq   \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}} |f_n(x)|^2dx $$

Under the interchange $x \leftrightarrow 1 +\frac{1}{n+1} - x$ the integral becomes

$$= \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}}\left[(n+1)\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]^2dx = \frac{1}{3(n+1)}$$

Comment: @Winther yes thank you for the correction. I have fixed it.